# Combine two sheets in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to combine two sheets in a Google Sheet.

The first sheet contains a simple list of names similar to this:

```
+--------+  
|  Name  |  
+--------+  
| Bob    |  
| Vivian |  
| Fred   |  
+--------+
```

The second sheet contains a list of tasks similar to this:

```
+------------+---------+  
|    Task    | Task ID |  
+------------+---------+  
| Do Dishes  |       1 |  
| Vacuum     |       2 |  
| Do laundry |       3 |  
+------------+---------+
```

I want to combine these so that I get a sheet with those tasks for each name in separate rows:

```
+--------+------------+---------+  
|  Name  |    Task    | Task ID |  
+--------+------------+---------+  
| Bob    | Do Dishes  |       1 |  
| Bob    | Vacuum     |       2 |  
| Bob    | Do laundry |       3 |  
| Vivian | Do Dishes  |       1 |  
| Vivian | Vacuum     |       2 |  
| Vivian | Do laundry |       3 |  
| Fred   | Do Dishes  |       1 |  
| Fred   | Vacuum     |       2 |  
| Fred   | Do laundry |       3 |  
+--------+------------+---------+
```

The real data sets are much bigger, so I need a formula to do this dynamically. I've tried to tinker with QUERY and VLOOKUP, but I'm really not getting anywhere.

Below is a shared sheet with the same dummy data as above. Any help would be much appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yosNoGj-PKf2Yua7-3mN3oCxIklr3IaBDojUgLunjWg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using a little math. On the what you want sheet, put your headers in row 1 (if you want to get fancy, you could make them formulas = to the titles from the other sheets so you stay consistent if you rename). I am assuming names are in Column A.
In A2 of the what you want sheet, put, `=index(Names!A:A,2+QUOTIENT(row()-2,3))`, and then drag it down. That will do each Name 3 times. [if you end up with more columns on the task sheet, increase the 3, or make it a function].
Now in B2 place `=index(Tasks!A:A,2+mod(1+row(),3))` and drag that right into column C and down (for both columns) as far as needed. That will cycle through the entries for each user.
I like how clear the question is.

EDIT: Here are the same formulas adapted to handle varying numbers of tasks.

```
=index(Names!A:A,2+QUOTIENT(row()-2,countA(Tasks!A:A)-1))
```

and

```
=index(Tasks!A:A,2+mod(countA(Tasks!A:A)-3+row(),countA(Tasks!A:A)-1))
```

If you want it to be a smidge more tranparent you could use `countA(Tasks!A$2:A)` in place of `countA(Tasks!A:A)-1)`, and change the -3 to a -2 (where 2 is the row where the data start and the -1 is gone because the header "Task" does not count as a task).

Comment: Thank You. I'm going to give that a shot

Comment: Thank you. Your edits make a big difference to match the use case.

My only issue is that I can't these to work as Arrayformulas. I'm always confused by which types of formulas will work and not. The requirement to drag down the formulas may cause issues as I don't really have any control over when and how much the data grows.

Comment: Here are my "final" formulas:  
=index(Names!A:A,2+QUOTIENT(row()-2,countA(Tasks!A$2:A)))  
=if(ISBLANK(A2),,index(Tasks!A$2:A,1+mod(countA(Tasks!A$2:A)-2+row(),countA(Tasks!A$2:A))))  
I added the ISBLANK test to be able to drag down all the formulas without getting tasks showing up in rows without a name